# SQL Query Replace Empty with Zero - OBIEE

Tags: sql, obiee, qsqlquery

Good afternoon,

Can someone help me with the following question?

If any of the values under code:02,code:03, code04 is blank my calculation do not work, how can I replace what I believe are empties for a 0 (zero)?

SQL query:

(FILTER ("Account Revenue"."Sales Revenue USD" USING ("Account Revenue"."Cd" ='04'))-FILTER ("Account Revenue"."Sales Revenue USD" USING ("ESP"."Account Revenue"."Cd" ='03')))

[image: RESULTS]

Comment: `coalesce()` I suspect.

Comment: If the columns are numbers and empty, they must be null. When you do the calculations, try using ISNULL(Cd, 0) to fill in the blanks with zero.